# retrieving id and incrementing it swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a id whose format is `1223-3939-ABC.1` and I would like to retrieve the last value i.e. 1 and increment it so now it looks like `1223-3939-ABC.2`. But its possible that "1" is not there so in that case, I would like to append ".1"

I am trying to achieve this in Swift and here is my code:

```
var deviceId: String = "1234-ASCD-SCSDS.1"

    if (deviceId != "") {
        var id: [String] = deviceId.components(separatedBy: ".")
        if let incrementedId: String = id.capacity > 1 ? deviceId.components(separatedBy: ".")[1] : "" {
            if (incrementedId == "") {
                //should append to id
                var firstEle = deviceId.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
                firstEle.append(".")
                firstEle.append("1")
                deviceId = firstEle
            } else {
                // retrieve that id, convert to int, increment id, convert back to string and replace the old id with new id
                let newId: Int = Int(deviceId.components(separatedBy: ".")[1])! + 1
                deviceId = deviceId.replacingOccurrences(of: ".\\d", with: ".\(newId)", options: .regularExpression)
            }
        }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems, such as

- Wrong usage of `capacity` (as already said by Nikita),
- Your code assumes that there is only a single dot, so that `id`
  has exactly two elements.
- Your code will crash if the dot is not followed by an integer.

The main problem is that

```
deviceId = deviceId.replacingOccurrences(of: ".\\d", with: ".\(newId)", options: .regularExpression)
```

replaces *all* occurrences of an arbitrary character followed by
any digit with `".\(newId)"`. It should probably be

```
deviceId = id[0] + ".\(newId)"
```

instead.

But the entire problem can be solved much easier:

- Find the last occurrence of a dot.
- Check if the part of the string following the dot can be converted to an integer.
- If yes, replace that part by the increased integer, otherwise append `.1`

Both checks can be achieved with conditional binding, so that the
if-block is only executed if the device id already has a trailing
number:

```
var deviceId = "1234-ASCD-SCSDS.1"
if let pos = deviceId.range(of: ".", options: .backwards),
    let id = Int(deviceId.substring(from: pos.upperBound)) {
    deviceId = deviceId.substring(to: pos.upperBound) + String(id + 1)
} else {
    deviceId = deviceId + ".1"
}
print(deviceId) // 1234-ASCD-SCSDS.2
```

Comment: Nice suggestion on rewriting the code, there is an easy win with just replacing a regexp.

Comment: @NikitaLeonov: You are right (didn't see your edit while writing the answer), but it still crashes on ill-formed input.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your regular expression for replacing is `.\\d` where `.` is actually any symbol. Replace it with `\\.\\d` and it will operate as expected.
2. You are referencing `capacity` but you need to reference `count` to understand an amount of components.

Based on [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538388-capacity):

> Capacity – the total number of elements that the array can contain without
>   allocating new storage.